# How to add note and reduce the margin to figure in latex

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

I have two figures. But I want to used them as one figure in latex. I want to add note for them. For example (a) bellows first figure and (b) for second figure. I used below code but the margin top between (a) and figure is too large. Is it possible to provide better way? Thanks

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}
 \centering{ \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig1a.png}}
 \caption*{(a)}
 \centering{ \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig1b.png}}
 \caption*{(b)}
  \caption{This is main caption for both}
  \label{fig:9}
\end{figure}
```

This is my expected
[image]

If it is possible, let try with second case
[image]

Comment: I would say: package `subfig` ?

Comment: Yes. It is subfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `subfig` package you could do as it follows:

**First case**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig1a.png}}\\ 
    \subfloat[]{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig1b.png}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use `\\[<value>]` to add more vertical space between your subfloats.

**Second case**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig1a.png}}\qquad
    \subfloat[]{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Fig1b.png}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Change `\qquad` if you want more horizontal space between your subfloats.

---

Add `captionskip=<value>` in `\captionsetup{}` to set the vertical space between a subfloat and its subcaption.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments to your question I guess you are using the `subfig` package` Your code doesn't tell because it doesn't seem to use its commands…

Your usage of `\captionsetup` suggests that you're loading the `caption` package. Then I'd use the `subcaption` package from the same author for having subfigures. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% I use demo because I don't have the figures

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}% <= this belongs in the preamble!

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Fig1a.png}
    \caption{First graphic}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Fig1b.png}
    \caption{Second graphic}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{This is main caption for both}
  \label{fig:9}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an example for the usage of the `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% I use demo because I don't have the figures

\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\captionsetup{labelfont={bf}}% <= this belongs in the preamble!

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[First graphic]{\includegraphics{Fig1a.png}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[First graphic]{\includegraphics{Fig1b.png}}
  \caption{This is main caption for both}
  \label{fig:9}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few more general comments:

- `\captionsetup{}` should go in the preamble for having a consistent layout
- `\centering` does *not* have an argument. Writing

  ```
  \centering{foo}
  bar
  ```

  will still centre `bar`
- having `[H]` as float specifier defeats the purpose of having a float in the first place. Are you really sure you need it?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exactly what I need. However it is difficult to choose one of two ans. So let accept for nearest my question